# Left join using LINQ with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

When I try to join multiple tables by using .net core with Entity Framework Core, I'm getting the following error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression1.GetArgument(Int32 index)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.QueryFlattener.Flatten(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)

My code:

```
var userBasicInfo = (from ubi in idamDbContext.UserBasicInfo
                     join c in idamDbContext.Center on ubi.CenterId equals c.Id
                     join t in idamDbContext.Territory on ubi.TerritoryId equals t.Id
                     join r in idamDbContext.Registration on ubi.UserId equals r.UserId                                 
                     into parent
                     from p in parent.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where ubi.SsdsId == ssdsId
                     select new
                         {
                             BirthDate = ubi.Birthdate,
                             CenterId = ubi.CenterId,
                             Email = ubi.Email,
                             FirstName = ubi.FirstName,
                             LastName = ubi.LastName,
                             Login = ubi.UserName,
                             SSDSRefId = ubi.SsdsId,
                             TerritoryId = ubi.TerritoryId,
                             UserId = ubi.UserId,
                             Gender = ubi.Gender,
                             UserTypes = ubi.UserId,
                             ContractID = p.ContractId,
                             CenterRefID = c.ReferenceCenterId,
                             CenterName = c.Name,
                             CountryRefID = t.ReferenceTerritoryId
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have to get data from the above four tables whether the ContractId exists from the Registration table or not. If exists it'll return an entire data or else ContractId should be return null.

Could you please share your thoughts if you anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
Parthiban.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug or whether it will remain intended behavior in ef-core, but at present it seems you have to use `p != null ? p.ContractId : 0`, not the preferred `(int?)p.ContractId`. But I must say I couldn't reproduce the exact error, only a null object reference error in an outer join (with client-side execution disabled).

Comment: Yes, you are right @GertArnold. It's an object reference null exception. As you mentioned above p != null ? p.ContractId : "" code I can able to fix it. I'm very new to the LINQ joins using entityframework core. Thanks for your quick response.